# IIS ARR redirects don't work

Tags: iis, application-pages, redirect

I have an ARR redirect rule in my SharePoint 2019 site, to redirect from some external 404 links:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Fix broken site links" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="/_layouts/path/to/some404/(.*)" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="/" redirectType="Found" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

I have added this rule via the IIS manager to the site called `SharePoint - www.redacted.url` and can observe that the web.config in `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\www.redacted.url443` contains my rule.

This rule isn't working and I see the 'Sorry, something went wrong' error. The URL with a 404 is to a _layouts page, but when I repeat the process with a non-layouts URL, the only difference is a slightly different error page.

Do I need to do something extra to get SharePoint to follow my ARR rule?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I don't fully understand, removing the `_layouts` from the match pattern caused the redirect to suddenly work. I also had to **remove all spaces from the rule name**. So, to redirect from `/_layouts/someOldLayoutsPage.aspx` to `/_layouts/someNewLayoutsPage.aspx`, the rule would look like:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="WorkingLayoutsPageRedirect" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="/someOldLayoutsPage.aspx" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="/_layouts/someNewLayoutsPage.aspx" redirectType="Found" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Note the visible inconsistency with `/_layouts/` appearing on the outgoing url, but not on the incoming url. Go figure. Microsoft...